# How to create a custom software key UITextField/NSTextField

Tags: ios, macos, uitextfield, nstextfield

I want to create a custom `NSTextField/UITextField` like this for entering a software key (pardon my paint skills).

[image]

Does anybody have any suggestions as to how I should go about this?

My lazy solution would be to give it a placeholder string with spaces and dashes in between, and as they type just mask those dashes into their string.  But I wanted to see if anybody else had some input-- or if I should just go with your standard separate text fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    UITextField *firstPart = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: YOUR_FRAME];
    firstPart.placeholder = @"-";
    firstPart.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.view addSubview: firstPart];
    // Create others
}

-(IBAction)unlockBtnPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSString *softwareKey = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ - %@ - %@", firstPart.text, secondPart.text, thirdPart.text];
}
```